# wireshark development: Registering heuristic function with multiple protocols in Lua

Tags: lua, wireshark

I'm writing a custom Lua dissector for a protocol that can be sent over both TCP and UDP. According to the README.heuristic file, this can be done using the following code:

```
/* register as heuristic dissector for both TCP and UDP */

heur_dissector_add("tcp", dissect_PROTOABBREV_heur_tcp, "PROTOABBREV over TCP",
               "PROTOABBREV_tcp", proto_PROTOABBREV, HEURISTIC_ENABLE);
heur_dissector_add("udp", dissect_PROTOABBREV_heur_udp, "PROTOABBREV over UDP",
               "PROTOABBREV_udp", proto_PROTOABBREV, HEURISTIC_ENABLE);
```

I have successfully implemented this for our dissector written in C/C++. However, the Lua implementation of proto:register_heuristic(listname, func) only allows one heuristic function to be registered per protocol object even though I'm using two unique heuristic list names.

Calls to:

```
my_proto:register_heuristic("udp", my_heur_func)

my_proto:register_heuristic("tcp", my_heur_func)
```

result in Wireshark displaying an error that my_proto already has a heuristic function registered. Inspecting the source, it appears the C code behind the Lua function checks against the proto name instead of the heuristic list name. Therefore, I can only register my heuristic function for a single heuristic list name.

Is this a Lua limitation or is there another way I can register my heuristic function with multiple heuristic list names? Short of another solution, it appears I may have to create two separate Lua dissectors. One for TCP and one for UDP.

Answer (score 0):

You could file a [Wireshark enhancement bug](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/), requesting that Lua dissectors be allowed to register to more than one heuristic table, just like built-in C dissectors can?